# Client side validation works for textbox but not multiline, in MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have made an dataannotation for a property `Note` , which is implementing `IClientValidatable` in order to get the data- attributes generated for the client validation to use.

```
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max 50 characters")]

[TextNumberCommaDotSpaceValidation(ErrorMessage = "Letters, numbers, ',', '.', only.")]

[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]

public object Note { get; set; }
```

The following jquery is used for unobtrusive validation:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("textnumbercommadotspace");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("textnumbercommadotspace",
    function (val, element, other) {            

        var textnumbercommadotspacevalidationattributePattern = /^[a-öA-Ö0-9  .,]*$/

        return textnumbercommadotspacevalidationattributePattern.test($.trim(val));

    }
);
```

Validation works fine when I am not using the `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` annotation. That is when validation is applied to an input text.

Does anyone know how to make client validation work with MultilineText?

The validation is fired but it does not present any error in the interface when used with a MultilineText.

Comment: Can you show us the source for `TextNumberCommaDotSpaceValidationAttribute` ?

Comment: ...and also your view source would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Validation for the MultilineText seems to work now but only on submit when the .valid() method is called.

But there is no error for onchange like i get when using a textbox and also there is no red marking around the MultilineText on error.

Is this red marking and validation onchange only for textbox and not for MultilineText?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this to your css file

```
textarea.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}
```